# Chrome loads a websocket very slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple AngularJS page fetching data from a server. The server in-turn gets this data from a TCP connection. All this happens in real-time. The data being fetched is weather data, and gets updated every five seconds.

Below are attached two images, showing the response in chrome and firefox, both upon reload.

[image: Response on reload in Chrome]

and [image: Response on reload in Firefox]

As can be seen the **GET with status 101** takes a whopping 1.4 mins on Chrome whereas takes only 2ms on Firefox. Why is this the case ?

I have repeated this experiment several times, with same result.

My Chrome is : 37.0.2062.68 beta-m 
and Firefox is : 31.0, both latest as of this writing.

I have also tried in Comodo Dragon, some version and it behaves like firefox. 
Code for controller, index.html and webserver can be found here: https://github.com/chintanp/weather_station/tree/master/angulared

Comment: I have tried deleting the history and cookies, though that also doesnt seem to help.

Comment: I am guessing this has something to do with chrome choosing long-polling over websockets. Though, I am not sure what is the best way to overcome this problem yet.